# How to change position of record in the grid permanently

Tags: extjs6-classic

I have problem with changing position of the records which are displaing in the grid. I have added arrows into column and wrote handler like below:

```
{
text: "Down",
width : 80,
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
tdCls : "row-shifter",
icon: appContext + "/images/arrow-dark-down-40.png",
handler: function(grid,index,c,d,f,row){
   if(index >= grid.all.endIndex){
      return;
   }
             index++;
             grid.store.remove(row, true);
             grid.getStore().insert(index, row);
},
   dataIndex : "Down",
   textResource : "Down"
}
```

When i click arrow button, the row is moved correctly but when i change displayed page (via pagination) the old records order is back. What should i do to do this changes permanent?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a new approach... You should set a new field to your model, call it 'order' for example with type 'number', then add sorter to your store to sort by this new field.
In your handler, just set a new value to the order field of the record according to the direction (add for up, subtract for down) and you have the up and down effect on the rows. This will also handle the paging correctly.
And its easier to restore the rows order if you save the order field with the rows.